Opentelemetry spring mongodb instrumentation
How can I configure Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer tracing to send traces to X-Ray instead of Jaeger, and also enable instrumentation to generate traces for communication with MongoDB, which I currently don't see visualized?
Here my current related dependencies I'm using:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Adds the Tracer Implementation -->
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Adds an exporter to store the traces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
</dependency>

It's not clear to my how to manually instrumenting my project in order to generate mongodb traces.
Any ideas?
